# Mi formulario de login.php no inicia sesion

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Espero que esten bien. Quiero comentarles mi error ya que no logro comprender que es lo que está mal.
Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro e inicio de sesion. Todo lo demas funciona de maravillas y lo he testeado. Pero aqui mi error:
Mi codigo, perteneciente a "login.php", no se ejecuta como es debido, de alguna forma no reconoce el condicional que veran dentro del codigo entero:

```
$errores_de_inicio = array();


//vamos a ver si llenaron el formulario
if(isset($_POST['ingreso'])){
    //agarramos la data del login form
    $username = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = md5($password);
    //agrego errores
    if(empty($_POST['usuario'])){
   array_push($errores_de_inicio, "El nombre de usuario no puede quedar vacío");
}
if(empty($_POST['password'])){
    array_push($errores_de_inicio, "La contraseña no puede quedar vacía");
}
    //conectamos
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '[miusuario]', '[mejorcensuramos]', 'registro');
    //hacemos magia con la database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = '$username' AND pass = '$password' AND active = 1";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) != 0){ /* No reconoce absolutamente nada de lo que hay dentro
                                            de este condicional, solo ejecuta el }else{}*/
        //procesa el logueo
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $verificado = $row['active'];

        if($verificado == 1){
            //continua
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
            header("Location: inicio.php");
        }else{
            array_push($errores_de_inicio, "La cuenta no fue verificada aun. Revisa tu mail o sino en SPAM");
        }
    }else{ //ESTE }ELSE{}
    array_push($errores_de_inicio, "Los datos ingresados no pertenecen a nuestra base de datos");
}
}
?>
```

Amaria su ayuda, desde ya disculpen si formulé mal mi pregunta. Me he cerciorado antes que el formulario sea metodo POST, su action="" y las cajas de .
No se si tiene algo que ver que en 'inicio.php' haya agregado

````
    session_start();
}else{
    header("Location: login.php");
    array_push($errores_de_inicio, "Debes iniciar sesion para continuar");
}
?>```
````

Comment: A primera vista aparenta estar correcto. Escribe un `var_dump($db, $resultado);` justo después de `$resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);` a ver qué sale.

Comment: Hola aeportugal! gracias por responder. Acabo de agregarlo y no se imprime nada en la pantalla.. me estoy volviendo loco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te comento que para mejorar tu codigo deberas crear un archivo connect.php con las funciones OpenConn y CloseCon($con) esto para que sea mas funcional tu codigo, en cuanto a tu pregunta es mejor hacerlo con queries preparadas para poder determinar el valor de la consulta deberia quedar algoa si:

connect.php:

```
<?php

function OpenCon(){

     $dbhost = "localhost";
     $dbuser = "user";
     $dbpass = "password";
     $db = "database";

     $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);

     if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

     return $conn;
}

function CloseCon($conn){
     mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Tu consulta deberia quedar mas o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
include("connect.php");
$con = OpenCon();//Se instancia la coneccion
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = ? AND pass =? AND active = 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);// Se prepara la consulta
$stmt->bind_params("ss",$username,$password);//Se pasan los parametros
$stmt->execute();//Se ejecuta la consulta
$result = $stmt->get_result();//Se obtiene el resultado
$stmt->close();//Se cierra el objeto statement
CloseCon($con);//Se cierra la coneccion a la BD
if($result){//Aqui ya validas que el usuario exista o no
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();//Se pre interpretan los datos
    /*TODO*/
}else{
    /*TODO*/
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ivan, estoy escribiendo tu codigo e interpretando para saber con exactitud que es lo que se va a ejecutar, y por supuesto anotando para aprender. Unas ultimas consulta: las funciones `OpenCon();`  `CloseCon();` y la variable `$stmt` son predefinidas por PHP? Porque cuando lei la documentacion creo que las pase de alto jeje.

Comment: No hay de que y no, las funciones `OpenCon()` y `CloseCon()` son funciones creadas por el usuario, sin embargo es una buena practica que sea descriptiva y ademas tiene mejor estructura para realizar modificaciones futuras y sobre el `$stmt` es una variable llamada asi pues es un _statement_ de hecho lo puedes ver mas claramente en [mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) y en [Mysqli SELECT query with prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select) es solo una nomenclatura estandar

Comment: Gracias Ivan, Estoy probando el script y me redirige a mi misma pagina de login pero en blanco. El codigo que agregué luego de `if($result){
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();` es: `$user = $result->fetch_assoc();//se pre interpretan los datos
        $verified = $row['verified'];
        
        if($verified == 1){ //si active es igual a 1 entonces inicia sesion
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: inicio.php");` ¿Ves algo incorrecto ahi? ¿Que significa la "ss" en el parentesis de `bind_params`? Muchas gracias por tu tiempo querido Iván.

Comment: Cuando haces un bind_param el primer parametro es el tipo de dato correspondiente a cada una de las variables de entrada que es poniendo, por ejemplo si en tu consulta tienes algo asi `WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ? AND active = ? AND verified = ?` tu bind_params deberia quedar asi `bind_params("ssii",...)` donde _s_ es un string e _i_ es un dato integer, ahora en cuanto a tu codigo despues de tu validacion no retornes por `header(....)` ya que los headers ya fueron mandados para ese punto, mejor hazlo con JS [Redirect JS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp).

Comment: Valio la pena cada segundo que te leí. Voy a anotar todo esto que me dijiste y a investigar mas al respecto. Luego si quieres te envio un link a mi sitio de prueba para que veas como quedó :D

Comment: Me agradaria mucho verlo funcionando.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Ivan, espero que estes de maravillas. Por cierto, me llamo Fabrizio. Queria hacerte una consulta. En active debo dejar el 1 y no agregarlo a `$stmt->bind_param` como una variable? Porque estoy teniendo problemas con la linea `$stmt = $con->prepare($query)`. Si puedes y quieres hablar por otro medio asi poderte pasar mis errores de forma mas dinamica (y sin molestarte obvio) avisame.

Comment: Hola Fabrizio, puedes meterlo como `bind_param` solo considera que si es mas de un parametro cambia la palabra reservada a `bind_params`, igual si encuentras una forma de contactarme por fuera sin exponer informacion personal con gusto.

Comment: Perfecto Ivan, aplicare tus correcciones y en caso de constancia de error intentare contactarte de la forma mas segura con todo el gusto. Gracias por tu buena predisposicion