# No me lee correctamente una variable de MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

Estoy trabajando con MySQL por medio de XAMPP.
no me esta detectando mi variable "rut" en la sigueinte linea de codigo:

```
if($rut == "1"){
header("Location: indexh.html");
}
else if($rut == "2"){
    header("Location: indexe.html");
}
else if($rut == "3"){
    header("Location: indexp.html");
}
else if($rut == "4"){
    header("Location: indexa.html");
}

else{
    //header("Location: login3.php");
    //echo $rut;
}
```

la variable "rut" la estoy tomando de MySQL con la siguiente linea:

```
$rut = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT rutina FROM login WHERE usuario = '".$nombre."' and password = '".$pass."'");
```

la base de datos tiene la tabla "login" con los campos "usuario, password y rutina, todos varchar"
a continuacion dejo el codigo completo:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre = $_POST["txtusuario"];
$pass = $_POST["txtpassword"];
$rut = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT rutina FROM login WHERE usuario = '".$nombre."' and password = '".$pass."'");

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = '".$nombre."' and password = '".$pass."'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
//$query2 = mysql_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login ")
if($nr == 1)
{
    if($rut == "1"){
    header("Location: indexh.html");
    }
    else if($rut == "2"){
        header("Location: indexe.html");
    }
    else if($rut == "3"){
        header("Location: indexp.html");
    }
    else if($rut == "4"){
        header("Location: indexa.html");
    }

    else{
        //header("Location: login3.php");
        //echo $rut;
    }

    //echo "Bienvenido:" .$nombre;
}
else if ($nr == 0) 
{
    //echo "No ingreso"; 
    header("Location: login.php");

}



?>
```

De antemano agradezco a quien se tome el tiempo de ayudarme.

Comment: Has comprobado que los índices del $post se llamen igual en PHP y en el name del formulario?

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada bienvenido.

## Detección de errores.

1. El primer error que veo en tu codigo es que estas redirigiendo con `header()` en ocasiones te va a mandar un error de que las cabeceras fueron enviadas con anterioridad.
2. El segundo error que puedo ver es que no estas usando queries preparadas, esto es nada mas por nomenclatura y funcion para tener un codigo mas claro, limpio y optimo, ademas de añadir una capa de seguridad contra inyecciones SQL
3. El tercer error es que tu variable `$rut` la estas inciando con la respuesta de la query cuando deberias interpretar la query para determinar la ruta

## Solución de errores.

El primer error lo puedes solucionar de la siguiente manera

```
  $URL="http://yourwebsite.com/";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">
```

La segunda etiqueta (`META`) es para cuando JS no este activo en el navegador, puedes leer de eso [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123470/redirect-in-php-without-use-of-header-method/27123606#:~:text=Replace%20the%20header('location,%220%3BURL%3D'%20.)

El segundo y tercer error lo puedes solucionar con este codigo

```
$con = OpenCon();
$query = "SELECT rutina FROM login WHERE usuario = ? and password = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_params("ss",$nombre,$pass);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rut="";
if($result){
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rut = $row['rutina'];
  }
}else{
    /*REDIRECT LOGIN FALLIDO*/
}
$stmt->close()
CloseCon($con);
/*TU CODIGO DE REDIRECCION*/
```

Espero haberte ayudado, si necesitas mas ayuda no dudes en preguntar.

Puedes ver la creacion de la variable `$con` y las funciones `OpenCon` y `CloseCon($con)` dando click [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361191/mi-formulario-de-login-php-no-inicia-sesion/361197#361197)

Puedes leer mas sobre queries preparadas [aqui](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select)